# Unable to locate package mintupgrade

Tags: linux-mint, upgrade

I was following these guides to upgrade Linux Mint 17.3 to 18:

- [Tecmint's, with pics](http://www.tecmint.com/upgrade-linux-mint-17-to-linux-mint-18/);
- [the Linux Mint's community's](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/2316).

I have done all the steps until the **mintupgrade** part. Here is what I've tried:

```
$ sudo apt install mintupgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mintupgrade

$ sudo apt-get install mintupgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mintupgrade
```

My software sources are pointed at:

```
Main (quina) http://packages.linuxmint.com
Base (trusty) http://archive/ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

How do I get mintupgrade?

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into this issue. I did the following for fresh install of mint 19. You might have to change to the distro you have(tricia, etc...):

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ tricia main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mint.list'
```

Do an update:

```
sudo apt update
```

Then add the keyring:

```
sudo apt-get install linuxmint-keyring
```

Comment: My PC showed Tara, didn't work with changing tricia to tara, but with leaving tricia it worked. HOWEVER, the tools cheekily reminds you it needs Tricia to work and Tara is too old :-p

Answer (score 0):

Closing my laptop halfway the update process from 18 to 19 might have been the reason for that. `mintupdate` got stuck with this error. But something like “Software Sources” in the menu also wouldn’t start.

My **boot menu** said 19.3 (tricia) (as did `cat /etc/linuxmint/info`), but a number of other places (`hostnamectl`, `inxi -Sr`) still mentioned 19 (tara)

For me the solution from @tldr of adding the `deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ tricia main` in the (before that empty or non existing) `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mint.list` file got me closer to the solution, but didn’t fully resolve it. And in addition gave me problems concerning double defined configurations:

```
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mint.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list:1
```

What eventually got me further was emptying the `mint.list` and putting/leaving/changing the `tricia` configuration in

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list`

so that it says `tricia` instead of `tara`. Then run

```
sudo apt update
Sudo apt upgrade

(sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade gave the same result)
```

And continue resolving issues from there. (Like solving `packages have been kept back:` [problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it). Among [others](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1893903#p1893903).)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to find negative information is difficult:-

remember minutupgrade will not exist for the latest version of Linux Mint until it is released by the development team.This can be some considerable after the version is released for a fresh install. so none of the tips above will help! (as i found out the hard way)

Answer (score -1):

Check that you are using the default software: Go into Software Sources. Click the tab on the bottom of the panel to select the defaults.

Update the cache using the command `sudo apt-get update` after that try to install mintupgrade

```
sudo apt-get install mintupgrade
```

Comment: This didn't work for me for upgrading 18.1 to 18.2.

Comment: This didn't work on Mint 18.3 to update to 19 either.

Answer (score -1):

got it running with resetting the packet sources to the defaults (no faster mirror), then it got found and was installed. And, guess what, my system wasnt completely patched,too.

[image: PacketSources - back to defaults]